# Firebase auth - Login and then redirect to app - How to fetch user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I have a react app that has login built into it, but have begun to break out the login/signup pages for architectural reasons.

The login is performed in a separate react app in a subdomain (https://login.mysite.com). After successful login the user gets redirected to the app (https://app.mysite.com). On logout the user gets redirected back to https://login.mysite.com again.

The redirect works as expected, but I cannot fetch the logged in user in my app (https://app.mysite.com). This causes an eternal redirect loop since the user is logged in at the login page, but not recognized as logged in at the app page.

Code from https://app.mysite.com

```
// app.mysite.com code
console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser) // This logs 'null'
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  console.log('user', user) // This logs 'null' - causing an eternal redirect loop
  if(user){
    // Render app here
  }else{
    const loginURI = 'https://login.mysite.com'
    window.location.replace(loginURI)
  }
})
```

Code from https://login.mysite.com

```
// login.mysite.com code
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    const appURI = 'https://app.mysite.com'
    window.location.replace(appURI)
  }
})
```

I guess the problem is that the logged in user cannot get fetched by the app?
The user is clearly logged in at https://login.mysite.com, but not at https://app.mysite.com.

How can I pass the logged in user from the login page to the app?

Kind regards /K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use multiple domain for same authentication.

Each domain/subdomain have their own cookies and localstorage and those can't be shared with another domain.

For your case login subdomain can't able to share credentials (auth token) with your app domain.

I highly suggest you to move from subdomain to path
Like `app.domain.com/login`

If you still want this with subdomain look for this [medium blog](https://dev.to/johncarroll/how-to-share-firebase-authentication-across-subdomains-1ka8)